# ¿Cómo hago para no confundirme entre "el doblez" y "la doblez"?

Tags: género, mnemonic

Generalmente quiero hablar de la parte del papel o de la tela que se dobló (el doblez), y no de la hipocresía o traición (la doblez).  Se me dificulta recordar cuándo se usa "el doblez" y cuándo "la doblez."  Pido un truco de memoria.

Comment: Para mi la palabra *doblez* es femenina en cualquiera de sus significados. De hecho los dos géneros son correctos en todas sus acepciones: [doblez](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E2lTW9l). Aunque también es cierto que es más habitual como lo expones en la pregunta: [doblez](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=doblez)

Comment: Diccionario panhispánico de dudas (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=doblez)

doblez. Aunque se documenta su uso indistinto en ambos géneros, es palabra mayoritariamente masculina cuando significa ‘parte que se dobla o pliega de una cosa’ y ‘señal dejada por un pliegue’: «¿Qué habría dentro de aquel doblez de la tela?» (González Dios [Méx. 1999]); y femenina cuando significa ‘hipocresía o falsedad’: «La mentira, la doblez, la manipulación y la amenaza desvirtúan la primitiva oferta» (Salarrullana Sectas [Esp. 1990]).

Comment: @blonfu - Ah, entonces ¿puedo hablar de una doblez en la papiroflexia (el origami)?

Comment: @RosieM.Banks - Si pones en una respuesta, pongo la palomita, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soy hablante nativo y he vivido en dos países de habla hispana, Argentina y España. Aun así no sabía que existía "la doblez" con este significado. Hoy he aprendido algo. Creo que difícilmente confundirás estas dos acepciones.

En términos más generales y sobre todo para palabras mucho más comunes en las que el género no es evidente, como paraguas o mapa, un buen *truco de memoria* es la práctica y en particular, leer. Con el tiempo te será más y más fácil.

Comment: Esta respuesta me recuerda mucho a [una de mis primeras respuestas aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16713/12637), que también fue tachada de no responder realmente a la pregunta. Fíjate que en realidad no la respondes, solo dices que "eso es así y con paciencia y tiempo lo aprenderás". Sería mejor que investigaras cuál es la diferencia entre ambas expresiones, y ayudar a quien pregunta a distinguir una de otra. Consulta la sección [answer] para más información. ¡Bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: Gracias, @istepaniuk.  Tu respuesta me da la idea que en la práctica sólo tengo que tener *el doblez* en mente.  (Voy a esperar un poquito antes de aceptar tu respuesta, para ver si alguien cuestiona esta conclusión.)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Charlie. Creo que la pregunta, que no es del todo precisa, poco tiene que ver con la diferencia entre ambas expresiones y en esa linea he intentado dar una respuesta. De todos modos la he editado intentando responder explícitamente lo que se pide; una ayuda a la hora de recordar el pronombre correcto.